# How to change character set of text in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, language, encoding, microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following issue with Excel 2013, which is still surprisingly lacking proper multilanguage support despite it being, you know, XXI century.

I have a **text** in **Excel 2013** which is displayed as 
**Êàïèòàëèçàöèÿ** (gibberish) instead of **Капитализация** (proper Russian word).

Now, from Notepad++ I'm able to do the following simple step to convert gibberish to Russian:

- Encoding - Character Sets - Cyrillic - Windows-1251

and the text converts from Êàïèòàëèçàöèÿ to Капитализация, which I can already copy&paste to any application in the usual way (the text encoding is ANSI per Notepad++, which seems to be the root of the problem since original source file was encoded with ANSI and not Unicode).

However, I can't seem to be able to do the same rather simple operation from within Excel 2013 (or, for that matter, the "uber powerful" text editor Word 2013).

That leads to **my question**: does anyone know a way to convert **character set** from **within Excel 2013** itself?

*As a side note* I know there are some encoding options when you use text importing wizard (which, as another side note, doesn't really pop up when you just double-click on a CSV file, you have to actually for some weird reason perform this operation from within Excel itself) which might or might not work, but I already reformatted the imported file and am looking for a simple solution to be able to do character set change from within Excel itself - in the same simple manner I'm able to do that in any self-respecting text editor

Cheers,

Eugene

Comment: [take a look at this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/translate-text-in-a-different-language-HA010354288.aspx)

Comment: I don't need to translate anything - both the gibberish text and the proper text are in the **same language** (and I am perfectly capable of doing a translation within the same language :)). I need to change encoding - i.e. I need to tell the stupid Excel to display text using different character set.

Comment: Oh, my bad! Would [this](http://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel) help?

Comment: Not quite - I know how to convert a text file - though I'd just use my regular text editor instead of that stupid import function. I need to be able to convert an already formatted table text within Excel. Maybe it's just not possible :(

Comment: Ah, I got nothing then, sorry!