# Excel: Change default encoding (file origin) of Text Import Wizard to UTF-8 (65001 : Unicode)

Tags: microsoft-excel, character-encoding, utf-8

I am using a variety of tools to regularly prepare data for the web. One stage requires me to open a CSV in Excel, make changes and save the file.

Is there a way to force Excel to accept UTF-8 encoding, and to save its files with that encoding?

Comment: To clarify, I would like to change a setting so that Excel assumes an input file is UTF-8 by default. As mentioned below, LibreOffice/OpenOffice does this.

Comment: If you don't actually have Unicode characters to deal with, I'd consider using a middleware to convert all CSVs to ASCII and then open in Excel.

Comment: Related question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel) but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I answered a similar question at [Default character encoding for Excel Text Wizard?](https://superuser.com/questions/1076240/default-character-encoding-for-excel-text-wizard/1179240).

I found my answer at [Changing default text import origin type in Excel](http://www.lukemiller.org/journal/2005/03/changing-default-text-import-origin.html).

1. Close Excel, if it is open.
2. Open the **Registry Editor**.
3. Navigate to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER → Software → Microsoft → Office → ▒▒ → Excel → Options**, where ▒▒ is your version of Office, mostly likely the largest number you see there.
4. Right-click an empty space on the right side and select **New → DWORD**.
5. Name the item **DefaultCPG**, and press Enter to save.
6. Right-click on **DefaultCPG** and select **Modify**.
7. Set the **Base** to **Decimal**.
8. For **Value data**, enter **65001** to set your default to UTF-8.  For some other encoding, use the code page identifier, which you can find in the Text Import Wizard in Excel or in [this list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers).
9. Click **OK**.

Like Vasille says in the comment to this question, if your file is not actually in UTF-8 format, you may technically want to convert the characters within the file to the encoding you want before opening in Excel. For my purposes, though, UTF-8 does a good enough job of displaying non-corrupted characters.

*Not working?  Make sure you set Base to Decimal (Step 7).*

[image: Screenshot of Edit DWORD 32-bit value showing setting base to decimal]

Comment: Are there any reasons *not* to do this? Why is this not the default behavior of Excel?

---

My team often deals with datasets containing foreign characters, and I'm wondering if there is any reason to not perform this action on each of our machines.

Comment: This unfortunately did not work on my machine. Files still open with default encoding (Win 7, Office 2016).

Comment: Doesn't work on mine also, Win 10 Office 2016

Comment: No dice.  Excel behaves as stupidly as ever.  One would expect an obvious feature like this to be accessible via a user preference in software as mature as Excel.

Comment: **IT WORKS!!!**  At first, I forgot to set the Base to Decimal.  After fixing that—and making sure the *Value data* is set to 65001 in decimal—the encoding in the Text Import Wizard now defaults to UTF-8. Hooray!!!

- - - -
I added an edit (pending approval) with a screenshot and a few minor clarifications. 
FYI, I am using Excel 16.0 (Office 365) on Windows 10.

Comment: @Robert H. Is there a way to achieve this on a Mac?

Comment: Can we clarify what this answer is supposed to achieve? After following the steps I thought Excel would open any file automatically with UTF-8 encoding i.e. double-clicking in Windows Explorer would open the CSV using UTF-8. That hasn't happened - it defaults back to ANSI like always. If I select "Import CSV" from the Data menu, UTF-8 is the default encoding - but I think it always was. EIther way, it's still a multi-step process to do something as simple as open a CSV in Excel. (Office 365, Win 10)

Comment: @Robert , do I need to **restart PC after the change in the Registry** ?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is required by Microsoft Office software.

1. Using Notepad++, convert the CSV using menu: Encoding -> Convert to UTF8-BOM.
2. Using the `sed` Unix utility, available in [cmder](https://cmder.net/) or [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/). See [Adding BOM to UTF-8 files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35807131/3735961).

   ```
   sed -i '1s/^/\xef\xbb\xbf/' file.csv
   ```

- Tested with Excel 2016
- This is what avwtp meant in their [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1431190/376144).

Comment: Setting the BOM in Notepad++ works perfectly fine.
Is there a command-line solution for Windows, like at CMD-Prompt or Powershell?

Comment: An answer for Python: 
f = open(out_filename, "w")
#set the BOM to UTF-8. Required for importing csv to Excel
f.write('\ufeff')

# Close the file
f.close()

Comment: Setting the BOM was the fastest and easiest. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

One easy way to change excel ANSI encoding to UTF-8 is the open the .csv file in notepad then select File > Save As. Now at the bottom you will see encoding is set to ANSI change it to UTF-8 and save the file as a new file and then you're done.

Comment: I will experiment with this. One problem I have is opening files consistently in the correct encoding so I do not get data in two encodings in a single results file. Then it becomes hard to fix. I really wish Excel allowed me a better way to choose input file encoding.

Answer (score 2):

I solved similar problem before. Unsuccessfully, but you can use [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/), which is UTF-8 in default.

Comment: LibreOffice is very handy for this. However, sometimes I have VBA macros to run. Thanks Lluser

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `File > Import` option and start with blank document and specify `UTF-8`

[image]

but this is far from optimal to make this a default setting for all files, anyway it is unnecessary to rotate the files around Google Drive or LibreOffice. The defaults are just badly chosen and the disability to change that is irritating.

**Related**

> 1. [How to set character encoding when opening Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel) but does not find the option to change the defaults such that all files are automatically opened with UTF-8 instead of Macintosh format in OSX
> 2. [How to change default file option to UTF-8 away from Macintosh file option](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270534/excel-how-to-change-default-file-option-to-utf-8-away-from-macintosh-file-optio) in Apple.SE.

Answer (score 0):

There's an Excel addin available [here](https://jaimonmathew.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/excel_addin_to_work_with_unicode_csv/) to work with Unicode CSV files that should help you.

Here's the developer Jaimon Mathew's note:

> Excel treats .csv files as text files and will replace all Unicode
>   characters with “?” when saved normally. If you want to preserve the
>   Unicode characters, you would need to save the file as “Unicode text
>   (*.txt)”, which is a Tab delimited file. Since I couldn’t find any
>   existing solution to preserve Unicode characters in CSV format, I
>   thought I’ll give it a go in creating an Excel Addin to do just that.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution, but it's an option: upload your Excel file to Google drive, open it with Google Tabs and download as a csv file.
It worked for me.

Comment: This does not answer the question how to change the encoding of Excel document.

Comment: Of course, when you open the CSV in Excel you lose the cell formatting so some numeric ID strings get converted to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a unix shell available (Cygwin), I append to the front of the csv file a little 3 char unicode ID (UTF-8) and then it reads fine into Excel and more importantly it is properly processed as input using VB Excel automation.

UTF-8.txt

EFBBBF << hex edit into a 3 char file.

cat UTF-8.txt file-to-use.csv > new_file.csv

Comment: (1) Can you describe how/why this works? (2) Can you describe *exactly* how to create this `UTF-8.txt` file?

Comment: I suggest using a hex editor and typing in the 3 character sequence.   Why it works, no idea.   I figured out this solution by taking an existing UTF-8 csv file, renaming it to txt, importing it into Excel (like suggested in other threads), saving it as CSV with the Unicode plugin (other thread) and then doing a binary diff of the two files.   The only difference was the 3 character starting sequence.

Comment: See this thread why it works [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)

Comment: In bash (OSX) `printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF' > new_file.csv` then cat the rest in - HT [@Yaron U](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729673/yaron-u).