# Default character encoding for Excel Text Wizard?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, encoding, utf-8

A large part of my job is to run an SQL query, save the results as a UFT-8 encoded csv file then import it into Excel for further manipulation and distribution.

When I import the csv file into Excel the first screen of the Wizard displays the default File origin: Windows (ANSI) and I often forget to change the Excel File Origin value to UTF-8. Is there a way to set the default to UTF-8?

Comment: There are several solutions in [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6002256).

Comment: I would only add that you can use Microsoft Access to create the import specifications and have it apply automatically every time you work with the CSV file. This way, you don't have to do any manipulation in Excel and you just load it exactly how you want it configured already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set character encoding when opening Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel)

Comment: Duplicate with more complete answer:  [Change default encoding of Excel to UTF-8?](https://superuser.com/questions/911369/change-default-encoding-of-excel-to-utf-8/1179248#1179248)

Answer (score 0):

I face routine tasks with a similar profile to what you described, and answers like those at [How to set character encoding when opening Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel) and [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically) miss the point. Like yours, my goal is to set a default encoding so that I don’t have to scroll down to near the end of the drop-down list just to choose “65001 : Unicode (UTF-8)” every single time I’m opening a CSV or tab-delimited-text file.

The answer that works for me is given at [Changing default text import origin type in Excel](http://www.lukemiller.org/journal/2005/03/changing-default-text-import-origin.html). It involves a registry edit (creating and modifying a value), so all the normal disclaimers apply (i.e., edit at your own risk and [back up the registry before editing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows)).

> You can change the default choice by running regedit from the `Program>Run` menu item. Once in the Registry Editor, navigate to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER>Software>Microsoft>Office>11.0>Excel>Options`
>
> Once here, you'll see a few registry entries for Excel 2003. 
>   Right click in the right-hand window and choose `New>DWORD` 
>   Call the new `DWORD` item `DefaultCPG` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
> Then right click on `DefaultCPG` and choose `Modify`. 
>   Set the `Base` to `Decimal`, and enter the decimal value for Unicode UTF-8 (`65001` in this case), then hit `OK`.

*(quoted from [Changing default text import origin type in Excel](http://www.lukemiller.org/journal/2005/03/changing-default-text-import-origin.html))*

The instructions are from 2005, but I found that they worked for Office 2016 if where the directions say “11.0” (as the Office version), I assumed “16.0” instead. I also closed Excel (and Outlook, with its Excel previewer) before making the edit, but I can’t confirm if that’s necessary.

Comment: Can you quote the relevant tasks from your links? This is in case the destination page is removed in the future. Please see [answer] and take our [tour] for more information.

Comment: Any hints on why this could not work? Just tried here and it didn't work. Should I restart the computer?

Comment: **It works!!!**  Make sure the Base is set to Decimal, and the Value data is set to 65001 (in decimal), as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rydq0.png).  This [duplicate post](https://superuser.com/questions/911369/change-default-encoding-of-excel-to-utf-8/1179248) has a slightly more up-to-date and complete answer.