# Change default text encoding in Excel 2019?

Tags: microsoft-excel, character-encoding

How can I change the default text encoding in Excel 2019?

I already tried this hack/workaround using the registry editor https://superuser.com/a/1179248/1468612
( based on this: http://www.lukemiller.org/journal/2005/03/changing-default-text-import-origin.html)
but sadly it seems to not be working for Excel 2019.

My standard encoding is windows-1252 but I have to work with
windows-1251 files a lot recently.

I am working with dozens of external Excel files each day so doing it for every single file is not a solution. It is driving me insane.

Edit :

I would like to change the standard encoding so when I open a file with double click the encoding would be already the correct one. Or at least the correct one would be already selected in the drop down menu of the text import wizard.

Comment: Which answer exactly didn’t work?  Please [edit] your question instead of replying with a comment

Comment: Give me 8 to 9 hours to figure out which answer your talking about. Clicking on the link brings you to the question but difficult to know which answer your talking about when you also see 3 answers all in a row.  I can also see the 3 deleted answers.

Answer (score 1):

For second link, the feature you can find from:

**Data**- **Get Data**- **Legacy Wizards**- **From Text(Legacy)**:
[image]

Then you can get this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is how I am doing it atm. But I would like to change the standard encoding so when I open a file with double click the encoding would be already the correct one. Or at least the correct one would be already selected in the drop down menu.

Comment: Maybe it's more related to orginal file?