# How to change a file's encoding?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, encoding

I am not sure if the question is the right one for my situation, but here is what I want to do:

I've downloaded a .csv file with Chinese characters in it. When opened with MS Excel, the Chinese characters will be displayed as question marks; but if I open it with MacOS's Numbers or Google Sheet, the Chinese characters can display.
I then open it with Atom, the characters originally show as question marks, and Atom "auto detect" the encoding to be UTF-8, but if I select encoding as "Chinese(GBK)", they display normally.

I also test it with notepad++, which seems to guess the encoding right as Numbers and Google Sheet do and display the right characters.

Now the question is, what should I do to THIS file so Excel can recognize it? Of course I can change the encoding in a working editor then copy all the content into notepad to create a new .csv file, but I am just wondering if there is anyway to change the original file's encoding?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set character encoding when opening Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I want to know if a file's encoding can be changed: Is the encoding method stored somewhere in the file and can be changed?

Comment: You'd have to start by opening the file with an application that understands the current encoding. The linked answer is still correct.