# How to change the formatting of German letters in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, cell-format

I have a CSV file with German words in its entries. Here's an excerpt:

[image]

As one can see, a number, a number of entries contain words with German words that contain characters that are depicted somewhat oddly. For instance, in C10 we see a “square root” symbol. Something similar happens in B6 and C5.

Here's the [xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eAt3pCsiuS8Z0g7J-hiwVb0Ih_Fjknd6/view?usp=sharing) and the [csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12yzF7ENTDZbhnyPAv9GljyYRPdTv8jgp/view?usp=sharing) files.

**Question**: how can I change the format of these letters in such a way that the correct (German) characters are depicted? If this is impossible, I would also be content with characters without accents (e.g., O instead of Ö).

Comment: can you create a small example csv file that demonstrates the problem, [edit] the post to include a link to it.  This way we can test different approaches.

Comment: Access denied on the link.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm now entirely how to add an example csv in the post. I've put a link to a public google document in the question instead, is that okay too?

Comment: @ScottCraner Better now?

Comment: I want the csv, not the xlsx file.

Comment: @ScottCraner I've added the CSV too. Either Excel or Google docs seems to have deformed it though.

Comment: the csv has the issues, you will need to just replace the errors with the correct characters.  This is not a formatting issue.  If the csv was correct then I would say that it was how the csv was opened in excel.  As is you will need to do a find/replace of each error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the character encoding of the file being imported. You can keep trying different encodings until you find one that works. Try UTF-8 first.

The easiest is to use import "from text" on the data ribbon.

Also see this post:
[How to set character encoding when opening Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel)