# How to change Excel character set?

Tags: microsoft-excel, character-encoding

I have an automatically-generated CSV file which contains accented characters. These appear fine when the file is opened with Notepad++. However, accented characters appear mangled in Excel (e.g. **é** appears as **Ã©**, **è** as **Ã¨**, etc.)

How do I change Excel's (*) charset so that it shows characters correctly? And what would be the correct charset (Unicode UTF-8, probably)?

EDIT: This is an automatically-generated file so it would be a hassle to manually do every time the import procedure described in [How to set character encoding when opening a CSV file in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-a-csv-file-in-excel) . I'm rather needing a setting to set in Excel once for all.

(*) Excel from Office 365, on my Win10 office computer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set character encoding when opening a CSV file in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-a-csv-file-in-excel)

Comment: This is an automatically-generated file so it would be a hassle to manually do every time the procedure described. Thank you anyway for your suggestion.

Comment: Did you read all the answers, or just the first one?

Comment: Your desired characterset is UTF-8. Excel currently is displaying the text with your local ANSI representation, so splitting up the multibyte chracters in two (or more) characters. The **Ã** is quite typical.

Comment: @Tetsujin I read all the answers.

Comment: There is no "setting" within excel to do this. You can write a re-usable procedure using Power Query or the Legacy import wizard to set the code page when you import the file. Or you can process the file before opening it in Excel to insert a `BOM` at the beginning of the file `EF BB BF` which will tell Excel it is UTF-8 encoding. There are examples of both on the stackoverflow forum.